# Receber o valor de um datepicker

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho um date picker assim

```js
$('#datepicker2').on('change', function() {
   console.log('Submiting form');
   console.log(this.value);
   $('#form1').submit();
   
  }).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<form action="" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return false" method="POST">
<input type="date" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">

</form>
```

E gostaria de saber como posso obter o valor do datepicker para fazer um select.
Uso a função onchange pois não quero ter um botão para fazer o submit mas sim quando o utilizador muda a data do datepicker.

Comment: Não basta submeter o form (retirando o onsubmit return false) e manipular os dados no seu action?

Comment: Se tirar o onsubmit return false a página fica num loop infinito a dar refresh

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ajustar 3 coisas em seu código:

1. Configurar o datepicker para fazer o submit do form quando usuário selecionar uma data
2. Setar o atributo `readonly` no input para evitar que o usuário digite datas inválidas
3. Previnir o evento de submit do form com `event.preventDefault()` para não dar refresh na página e enviar os dados via ajax

```js
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
    nextText: 'Próximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior',

    /**
     * @See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect
     */
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
      console.log(dateText);
      // usar o this aqui dentro faz referência ao campo
      //console.log($(this));
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
    }
});

$('#form1').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.serialize();
    var url = $this.attr('action');
    
    // debug
    console.log(data);
    
    $.post(url, data, function (response) {
       // debug
      console.log(response);
      alert('sucesso');  
    })
    .fail(function () {
      alert('Erro no ajax');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- <input type="date" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"> -->
<form action="ajax.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" value="13/06/2019" readonly>
</form>
```

**Arquivo ajax.php**

```php
<?php 
/**
 * A data virá no formato que o datepicker enviar
 * Nesse caso d/m/Y, Mysql trabalha no formato Y-m-d
 */
$data = $_POST['datepicker2'];

/**
 * Transforma a data para Y-m-d
 * Você poderia fazer isso com a classe DateTime também
 */
$data = join('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data)));


/**
 * TO DO 
 * - Connectar no banco
 * - Preparar a query
 * - Obter o resultado da query
 * - Retornar o resultado para o ajax 
 */
echo 'Data recebdida e já transformada no formado do mysql'. $data;
```

**Referências**

- jQuery datepicker [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)
- jQuery [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- jQuery [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- jQuery [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/#event-preventDefault)
- W3C [readonly](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) doc

**Sugestões de leitura**

- [Forms sem botão de submit são péssimos para usabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390661/submit-de-form-somente-com-a-tecla-enter-sem-bot%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona/390741#390741)
- PHP [PDO doc](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)
- PHP funçoes [json_*](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.json.php)

Comment: Até aqui tudo certo, porém como é que eu posso usar a variável $data para inserir na base de dados? diz-me que o index não existe.

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta e inclui a query que você está utilizando para inserir na base de dados para podermos te ajudar

Comment: A minha query é esta
```
$query = "SELECT sum(dinheiro) as dinheiro, nome FROM gastos g, subcategorias s where s.codsubcategoria=g.codsubcategoria AND dataa='".$_POST['data']."' AND utilizador='".$_SESSION['email']."' group by s.codsubcategoria";  
```
Eu preciso de usar a variável na mesma página ou seja a inserção está na mesma página "dashboard.php"

Comment: Se você estiver usando o exemplo do php que postei acima, trocar `$_POST['data']` para `$data` pode te ajudar. O nome da coluna usada na query é `dataa` mesmo (com 2 a) ou seria `data`.

Comment: Sim também já tentei com $data e diz que a variável não existe.
Sim o nome da coluna é dataa na base de dados

Comment: Lembre-se que `$_POST['data']` onde `data` tem que ser o mesmo valor usado no atributo `name` do campo. Na sua pergunta está outro valor `datepicker2`. Nesse caso seria `$_POST['datepicker2']`

Comment: Eu copiei o que você sugeriu, também tentei com o datepicker2 e diz undefined index.
Tem a certeza que a variável pode ser usada na mesma página?

Comment: Você pode tentar debugar `print_r($_POST); exit;` isso vai listar o array de post com seus respectivos valores

Comment: Aparece-me um array vazio... segui todos os passos

Comment: Na sua pergunta o `action`  da tag `form` está vazio. Se no seu código estiver vazio também ajusta ele para apontar para a página que processa os dados. `<form action="nome_do_arquivo.php">`

Comment: Então eu preciso de meter o action para a mesma página? E onde meto o código do ajax.php?

Comment: Ok já consegui meter isto quase a dar, havia uma falha no submit da form em que o nome da form é form1 e não form.
Porém agora quando eu mudo a data no datepicker ele não atualiza os dados com a data que eu selecionei, fica sempre com a data de hoje